# Reference current forms ID (Primary key)

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

Basically the form I have opened displays a set of data from a table. This data is a row in a table in the Access Database. I am trying to use vba to get the current ID of the form/row. An example of what I'm trying to do is in the code below:

```
If Me.process_status = 4 Then
    ssql = "UPDATE [activity_submissions_tb] SET [Edit] = True  WHERE" _ & 
    "submissionID =" & Forms![Form_Frm2_Activity_Submission_Edit]![submissionID]
    DoCmd.RunSQL ssql
Else
    ssql = "UPDATE [activity_submissions_tb] SET [Edit] = False  WHERE " _ &
    "submissionID =" & Forms![Form_Frm2_Activity_Submission_Edit]![submissionID]
    DoCmd.RunSQL ssql
End If
```

I am trying to update the table but cannot get the `WHERE` condition to work as I don't know what to put for *currentID*.

I do not know how I would go about getting the ID of the current form/row using vba. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you may find `currentdb.execute` a useful alternative to `docmd.runSQL`. [Here's](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/RunSQL_vs_Execute) a post on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
ssql = "UPDATE [activity_submissions_tb] SET [Edit] = True  WHERE [submissionID] = [currentID]"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `currentID` is not set to anything, I need it to refer to the current form's ID which i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Was pretty simple just didn't do enough research. A simple Me.submissionID did the trick.

Comment: `Forms![Form_Frm2_Activity_Submission_Edit].form![submissionID].value` should work equally as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want recordset.clone...

```
Dim rs as Recordset
Dim ID as Integer

Set rs = me.Form.Recordset.Clone
ID = rs![FieldNameID]
```

Or if you know the column number

```
ID = rs.Fields(0)
Debug.Print ID
```